# Automatically Save File as Text With Friday's Date

Tags: vba, excel

I recorded a macro that at the end saves the workbook as a text file and closes.

I would like to change the file name to Friday's date so that every week when I save it, the file name is different.

This is what the macro recorded

```
ActiveWorkbook.SaveAs Filename:= _
    "C:\Users\username\Desktop\Temp\\File2218.txt" _
    , FileFormat:=xlText, CreateBackup:=False
```

I tried to change it to

```
ActiveWorkbook.SaveAs Filename:= _
    "C:\Users\username\Desktop\Temp\File" & Text(Today()+2, "mdyy")& txt" _
    , FileFormat:=xlText, CreateBackup:=False
```

(The reason I did +2 is because it's always done one Wed, therefore +2 = Friday)

But it doesn't work.

Any help would be greatly appreciated!

Comment: change `& txt` to `& .txt`. You forgot the `.`

Comment: use `Environ$("USERPROFILE") & "\Desktop` to get the desktop folder for the current user. To list all the environment variables, execute `set` in a cmd  console.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Does the `C:\Users\username` folder actually exist? You will probably have to change `username` to your own username, or use `Environ$("Username")` like this:

```
"C:\Users\" & Environ$("Username") & "\Desktop\Temp\File"
```

And make sure the folder exists too, or you will get another error.

Also, use `DateAdd()` to add days:

```
NewDate = DateAdd("d", 2, Date)
```

And `Format$()` to format it (`Text()` is more of a worksheet function)

Once completed, you end up with this:

```
ActiveWorkbook.SaveAs Filename:= _
    "C:\Users\" & Environ$("Username") & "\Desktop\Temp\File" & _
     Format$(DateAdd("d", 2, Date), "mdyy") & ".txt" _
    , FileFormat:=xlText, CreateBackup:=False
```

Comment: Kudos for the `Environ$` suggestion (well the whole answer actually)! I'd even go as far as to recommend using `Environ$("temp")`, which gives a path to `C:\Users\(name)\AppData\Local\Temp` (well at least on Win7 Pro), a much more appropriate place to store per-user temp files IMO.

Comment: Or if the path must be under `\Desktop`, use `Environ$("userprofile")` to reliably get the `C:\Users\(name)` part.

Comment: The path was not the problem- I just removed the username for privacy purposes. Using most of what you said, I did `ActiveWorkbook.SaveAs Filename:= _
    "C:\Users\swall\Desktop\Temp\File" & _
     Format$(DateAdd("d", 2, Date), "mdyy") & ".txt" _
    , FileFormat:=xlText, CreateBackup:=False` and it worked beautifully!